# OnDemandGrid with dstore Tackable and Memory not showing complete data when data is set into it

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid, dstore

I have OnDemandGrid with dstore Trackable and Memory store associated with it. Initially, a memory store with empty array is set. When actual data is fetched and set into the grid, grid does not display full data. It always displays 100 rows.

Moreover, if any column is sorted, then it displays entire set of data.

Grid is created in following manner

```
this.grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection, ColumnHider,ColumnResizer,Keyboard, Selector]))({
                // use Infinity so that all data is available in the grid
                //className: "dgrid-autoheight",
                showHeader: true,  
                collection: self.memStore,
                minRowsPerPage : 100,
                bufferRows: 10,
                pagingDelay : 15,
                farOffRemoval : 2000,
                columns: modifiedColumnList,
                selectionMode: "extended",
                //pagingLinks: true,
                //pagingTextBox: true,
                //firstLastArrows: true,
                //rowsPerPage: 100,
                //pageSizeOptions: [100, 150, 250],
                adjustLastColumn : true,
                loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
                noDataMessage: 'No data.',
                allowSelect: function(row){
                    return true;
                },                  
                keepScrollPosition: true
            },this.domNode);
```

Memory store is created in following manner

```
 var TrackableMemoryStore = (declare([Memory, Trackable]));
```

Data is set in the following manner

```
self.memStore = new TrackableMemoryStore({ data: gridData, idProperty: "SRVC_ORDER_ID",defaultNewToStart : true });
            self.grid.set("collection", self.memStore);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an [issue](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/1251) identified in dgrid 0.4.1 and 1.0.0, which happens if you call `startup` on your grid before it is actually displayed.

In most cases, this is something that should be fixed in your own code, since `startup` should only be called after the grid's element is in document flow.  However, Dijit's StackContainer also happens to call `startup` on all of its children before they are really displayed, but typically gets away with it because it then calls `resize` when they're actually displayed.

There is a fix for this issue on the master, dev-1.0, and dev-0.4 branches, so if you use the latest commits from one of them, this should be resolved.

(Incidentally, in earlier versions, the grid would simply end up requesting all data from the store at once, which is definitely not a good thing for large or server-based stores.)

Comment: I am calling startup method on OnDemandGrid in the postCreate of Widget.

Comment: The widget extends "_WidgetBase", "_TemplatedMixin", "_WidgetsInTemplateMixin".

Moreover, I have tried calling grid startup after domReady. But it did not work.

Comment: I went through this link https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/1251.

My Grid is inside a TabContainer. Grid that has the issue is in Second tab and gets rendered when page is loaded. Then a button click triggers the data fetch call. Then I set the collection in the grid.

Comment: If you're inside of a TabContainer (which extends StackContainer), then you may very well be running into that issue that was fixed. Meanwhile, if your grid is a direct child of a dijit layout widget, you should be mixing in `dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry`.  Also, you're not mixing `_WidgetBase` and co. directly into a dgrid constructor, right?  That probably wouldn't work very well, given that dgrid already replicates dijit's lifecycle methods, and neither `dgrid/List` nor `dijit/_WidgetBase` expect anything else to define them before itself.

Comment: I tried using latest files from dev-1.0. But the issue is still present.

I am creating a dijit (or module) which extends "_WidgetBase", "_TemplatedMixin", "_WidgetsInTemplateMixin".

OnDemandGrid is instantiated in postCreate method of this Dijit (or module)

This module contains a simple template containing only one <div> element with id attribute

The module is instantiated and placed inside tab container like this

var Grid = new GridModule({gridController: this}, gridId);
var gridContainer = dom.byId(containerId);
Grid.placeAt(gridContainer);

Comment: Also I am not mixing _WidgetBase into a dgrid Constructor directly.

Comment: While debugging OnDemandList, I can see, that when I switch to the Tab containing OnDemandGrid, and scroll the grid, inside _processScroll method of OnDemandList, this.rowHeight is 0 and as a result it just returns.

While, when I sort the grid and do a scroll, this.rowHeight has non zero numeric value.

Comment: Moreover, when tab (tab container's tab) in which Grid is created is visible, and then data is loaded, entire data is shown.

But the problem is after scrolling once or twice, browser hangs and I have to kill the page.

Comment: `rowHeight` being 0 means you have either called `startup` on the grid too soon and/or haven't called `resize` at a proper time when the grid is actually in document flow in order to properly calculate it.  (The `resize` part of that is what the post-1.0.0 change addresses - in 1.0.0 and 0.4.0, you had no choice but to refresh/sort/etc. to get it to recalculate.)

Comment: I have fixed the data loading issue by programatically setting the rowHeight to its correct value by calling _calcRowHeight when grid becomes visible. But now the problem is, that after scrolling down the data in the grid , entire page freezes. Some of the parameters are minRowsPerPage = 100, bufferRows = 10, pagingDelay = 15, farOffRemoval = 2000, selectionMode is 'extended'.

Comment: The issue related to Page Freezing is also resolved. It was because, I was setting the row height incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks Ken for all the help.